# Windows 8.1 XML file saving

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8.1

I'm writing a simple Windows 8.1 (Modern/Metro) Application and I'm saving data in XML file. The code:

```
 private const string XMLFILENAME = "fileName.xml";
 var myCars = buildObjectGraph();

 var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Car>));
 using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(XMLFILENAME, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
 {
             serializer.WriteObject(stream, myCars);
 }
```

It works fine.
But... Where I can find this file? I searched it everywhere and I can't find this.
And second question: Is it possible to save this file where I want? For example, on my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [API Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx) you should check `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` (and `.Name` and `.DisplayName`).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to store data in a static path and check it will be there or not and after completed success then u have give dynamic path.